# Taking input using bufferedreader

Tags: java, input, bufferedreader

I want to take input in the format: `-prize 45`

This is my code

```
static double prize_input(String list[]) throws IOException{
    boolean flag=false;
    double p=0;
    while(true){
        if(list.length!=2 || ( list[0].compareTo("-prize")!=0 ) ){
            System.out.println("usage: -prize <Itemprize>");
            flag=true;
        }
        else
        {
                try{
                    p=Double.parseDouble(list[1]);
                    flag=false;
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    flag=true;
                }
        }
        if(!flag)
            return p;
        else
            list=br.readLine().split(" ");
    }
  }
```

When I input: `-prize abc` where second argument is also a string it prompts me for another enter key from user instead of display the appropriate message. Please tell me what am I missing and how should I correct it.

Comment: It is kind of  unclear what you are looking for. can you please explain your input and expected output for me ?

Comment: actually problem is that bufferedreader ignores \r and \n and I want to consider that, is there any way? the input should be read as a line only.

Comment: I really do not know. I usually use scanner did you try it?

Comment: No I haven't tried it.

Comment: I think nextLine() in scanner will lead to what u wanna. just google and read about it

Comment: can you tell me how much it helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`usage: -prize <Itemprize>` will be printed only if this condition will fail

```
if (list.length != 2 || (list[0].compareTo("-prize") != 0))
```

so only if

- user *didn't* provided two elements,
- and if first element *is not* `-prize`.

Since for `-price aaa` both conditions are fulfilled so user will not see this info, but `flag` representing correctness of data will be set to `false` while failed parsing second parameter, so in

```
else
    list = br.readLine().split(" ");
```

program will be waiting for new data form

To improve user experience you should print usage info right before reading new data from user, so try moving line

```
System.out.println("usage: -prize <Itemprize>");
```

right before `br.readLine()`

```
else{
    System.out.println("usage: -prize <Itemprize>");
    list = br.readLine().split(" ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working perfectly now without using scanner and not asking me to press any key after entering even wrong input like -prize aa. What was the problem it had can you explain?

Comment: You printed info asking for new data only if previous data didn't contain two elements, or if first parameter wasn't `-prize` but you didn't print it after confirming that second parameter is wrong (in `catch` block). So instead of printing it in two places print it only once, when you are sure that data was wrong. Best place for it is right before you execute `readLine()` which will wait until user will provide new data.

Comment: @puppy7 BTW, instead of cryptic `list[0].compareTo("-prize") != 0` you can use `list[0].equals("-prize")` which is easier to read, write, maintain, and is standard way to compare objects (like Strings).

Answer (score 0):

your condition is worng as you are taking while(true) as a loop condition and also you are taking a input in which loop will go as forever and also buffer reader waits for the next line to be splited.